# What happened to Torah she be al peh in the generations before Yoshiyahu HaMelech?

Tags: tanach

I get the impression from learning about Yoshiyahu HaMelech that the country as a whole almost entirely forgot about the Torah altogether in the previous generations, until he discovered the Sefer Torah and reinstituted keeping the Torah and serving Hashem.  Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding?  If so, how was Torah she be al peh transmitted from before these generations as Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi didn't write down the Mishna until a few hundred years later?  Were there a core of people who continued to learn it?  Was a lot lost?  Do we know?

Comment: Imagine that "core of people" would have been the neviim as recorded in the Rambam's intro to the Mishna Torah - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Transmission_of_the_Oral_Law.6 - so since Yirmiyahu intersected with Yoshiyahu, we go backwards in time to Tzefania then Nachum, etc.

Comment: @EraserX I should have thought of that!  It doesn't entirely answer the whole thing though, but I should probably ask a separate question on how much of the oral law we lost down the chain of transmission before it was codified at various points

Comment: If anything it was the opposite. That generation primarily relied on Torah S’Baal Peh because Menashe had destroyed almost every extant Sefer Torah in the part of Eretz Yisroel that he ruled over.

Comment: @Schmerel is there a source for that - I thought there was general ignorance and idol worship?

Comment: . During the first thousand years of Jewish history  Torah was almost completely learned orally with written books rarely consulted.  How and  why would Menashe destroying Sifrei Torah have any impact  on that?  Idol worship there was like any other Yetzer Hora or averos done.

Comment: @Schmerel That's a good question.  I thought that I had heard that most of the country had completely forgotten about the Torah, but it is many years since I first learned that part of Nach, so I can't remember if there was a source for that or I was just reading into it something that wasn't there

Comment: The only place I've ever seen the claim that  the Torah in itself was forgotten during that time period was on anti-frum blogs. From a superficial reading of the story the reaction Yoshiyahu and the  people around him had to finding the Sefer Torah makes it  clear that they knew what it was. Even if they had never actually seen one.

Answer (score 2):

No, there was always a very special core, and not much was lost. It's all brought in sefer Avodat haKodesch by Ibn Gabbai, the entire transmission and in particular the oral and mystical.